# jquery and xml. Getting nodes as list items

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, html-lists

I am trying to parse some xml and most of it is fine. However, I am having trouble getting nodes into and creating list items. my code so far is something like

```
$(xml).find('section1').each(function (i) {
   var myLink = $(xml).find('link').text();
   $('#set1').find('ul').eq(i).append("<li>"+myLink+"</li>");
});
```

but what happens is it takes all of the "myLinks" nodes and puts them in one `<li>`. Any ideas on crating an `<li>` for each `myLink` node?

Thanks

Comment: just in case that didn't past right. second line should be$('#set1').find('ul').eq(i).append("<li>"+myLink+"</li>");

Comment: @user: fyi: you can edit your question by clicking `edit` below the tag list

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to change `$(xml)` to `$(this)` inside your loop?

And fixup the append code (you only have one list, right? if so, remove the `.eq` stuff) like this:

```
var $list = $('#set1').find('ul');

$(xml).find('section1').each(function () {
   var myLink = $(this).find('link').text();
   $list.append("<li>"+myLink+"</li>");
});
```

If that works, you might be able to simplify it down to this:

```
var $list = $('#set1').find('ul');

$(xml).find('section1 link').each(function () {
   var myLink = $(this).text();
   $list.append("<li>"+myLink+"</li>");
});
```

And perhaps even further using `$.map`

Comment: thanks for the response. I am actually trying to create a new list item for each node. ex my xml is <section1>
    <title>My Title1</title>
    <ImagePath>path</ImagePath>
    <links>
      <link>title 1</link>
      <link>title 2</link>
    </links>
  </section1> so the two links would each be their own list item. However they are both being put into a single list. Which makes since with how I did it, but not sure how to go change it to work.

Comment: Your code, `$('#set1').find('ul').eq(i)`, implies you have lots of separate lists (ULs). If you have only one, you shouldn't be using `.eq(i)` here.